# Wrong View create PDF laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

On a button click I want a PDF. But I dont get a PDF I just get the data from the database.

My code is:

```
<?php

namespace MVS\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;
use MVS\Kunden;

class DynamicPDFController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     $customer_data = $this->get_customer_data();
     $finance_data = $this->get_finance_data();
     return view('dynamic_pdf')->with('customer_data', $customer_data);
    }

    function get_customer_data($id)
    {
     $customer_data = Kunden::find($id);
     return $customer_data;
    }

    function pdf()
    {
     $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
     $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_customer_data_to_html());
     return $pdf->stream();
    }

    function convert_customer_data_to_html()
    {
     $customer_data = $this->get_customer_data();
     $output = '
     <h3 align="center">Angebot</h3>
     <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;">
      <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="20%">Vorname</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="30%">Nachname</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">Stadt</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">PLZ</th>
   </tr>
     ';  
     foreach($customer_data as $kunden)
     {
      $output .= '
      <tr>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->vorname.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->nachname.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->wohnort.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->plz.'</td>
      </tr>
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
     return $output;
    }
}
```

I just get the following message output:

> {"id":1,"created_at":"2018-10-15 06:56:15","updated_at":"2018-10-15 06:56:15","user_id":2,"vorname":"Patrick","nachname":"Marks","strasse":"teststraße 9","plz":47906,"wohnort":"Krefeld","mail":"p-dierig@sdsd.de","telefon":21514462,"geburtsdatum":"2013-10-30"}

The route is the following:

```
Route::get('/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');
```

When i use this code in the controller:

```
function index()
    {
     $customer_data = $this->get_customer_data();
     return view('dynamic_pdf')->with('customer_data', $customer_data);
    }

    function get_customer_data()
    {
     $customer_data = DB::table('kundens')
         ->limit(10)
         ->get();
     return $customer_data;
    }
```

I will get a PDF with ALL customers in the table. But i only want from a specific User the data...

Comment: It seems like you are calling the `index` method on button click. Can you check if the correct controller method is being called?

Comment: I added teh route. Maybe it helps?

Comment: You are calling the wrong Controller action. `@get_customer_data` only gets the customer from the database and returns the model. You have to call the`@pdf`  action.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting a GET method onto

```
Route::get('/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');
```

Then you will hit `function get_customer_data(){}` in your `DynamicPDFController`

This hits onto this code:

```
$customer_data = DB::table('kundens')
         ->limit(10)
         ->get();
return $customer_data;
```

So you would only get the customers data.

Try changing this:

```
Route::get('/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');
```

To this:

```
Route::get('/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@index');
```

Now try chaning your get_customer_data to this:

```
function get_customer_data()
    {
     $customer_data = DB::table('kundens')->first();
     return $customer_data;
 }
```

This should give you only one customer.
Now we have to make it dynamic, so you can pass an ID or similar to the function:

```
function get_customer_data($id)
    {
     $customer_data = DB::table('kundens')->whereId($id)->first();
     return $customer_data;
    }
```

Remember to change your index function:

```
function index()
    {
     $id = 1;
     $customer_data = $this->get_customer_data($id);
     return view('dynamic_pdf')->with('customer_data', $customer_data);
    }
```

Now edit your index accordingly, so you can pass the ID to the index function for a dynamic setup.

Comment: Thats the best solution. I need to change $kunden->vorname to $kunden['vorname'] But now i have the next error: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag::$vorname (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mvs\mvs\resources\views\dynamic_pdf.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Because your codes calling users information check this route :

Route::get('/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');

in this route you are calling get_customer_data() function in DynamicPDFController class .

if we look at there :

```
$customer_data = Kunden::find($id);
     return $customer_data;
```

those codes response the json .

You can replace the functions like that :

```
function get_customer_data($id)
    {
     $customer_data = Kunden::find($id);


     return $this->pdf($customer_data);
    }

    function pdf($customer_data)
    {
     $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
     $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_customer_data_to_html($customer_data));
     return $pdf->stream();
    }

    function convert_customer_data_to_html($customer_data)
    {

     $output = '
     <h3 align="center">Angebot</h3>
     <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;">
      <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="20%">Vorname</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="30%">Nachname</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">Stadt</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">PLZ</th>
   </tr>
     ';  
     foreach($customer_data as $kunden)
     {
      $output .= '
      <tr>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->vorname.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->nachname.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->wohnort.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'.$kunden->plz.'</td>
      </tr>
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
     return $output;
    }
```